# How to create content depending on creation of an other content type with rules

Tags: rules

I am abandoned in case of the rules module.

Is there a way to create a forum every time a specified content type is created and give the forum the same title as the content.

I am using drupals forum module and a contetnt type named topic.

Now i like to force drupal to create a froum for each topic that will be created and to take the topic content type title as forum title  for the new created forum

I have no Idea which are the right conditions for the rules module

I am looking forward to see any ideas!

Thank you

Comment: I don't believe that's possible using the Forum or Advanced Forum modules. It could probably be done using Organic Groups if you wanted to convert

Comment: I have og_forum_d7 activated but I tried for mysqlf and in my opinion there is no way. Therefore I'm asking here.